# Create a matrix from a function and two numeric data frames

Tags: r

I'm trying to create matrices of various distance/association functions in R.  I have a function similar to cor that gives the association between two vectors.  Now I want to take a dataframe (or matrix) of numeric vectors, something like `mtcars`, and create a matrix from the function and data frame.  I thought this is what `outer` is for but am not getting it to work.  Here's an attempt using cor and `mtcars`.

```
cor(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)  #a function that gives an association between two vectors                  
outer(mtcars, mtcars, "cor") #the attempt to create a matrix of all vectors in a df
```

Yes I know that `cor` can do this directly, let's pretend it can't.  that `cor` just finds correlations between two vectors.

So the final goal would be to get the matrix you get from `cor(mtcars)`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `outer` with a function that takes column names or column numbers as arguments.

```
outer(
  names(mtcars), 
  names(mtcars), 
  Vectorize(function(i,j) cor(mtcars[,i],mtcars[,j]))
)
```

Comment: Both are really great ideas. T hank you very much guys. +1

Answer (score 4):

`outer` is not directly up to the job. It will just expand its `X` and `Y` vectors and call `cor` once. **EDIT** As @Vincent Zoonekynd shows, you can adapt it to work.

Otherwise, a rather simple loop does the trick:

```
m <- as.matrix(mtcars)
r <- matrix(1, ncol(m), ncol(m), dimnames=list(colnames(m), colnames(m)))
for(i in 1:(ncol(m)-1)) {
  for(j in (i+1):ncol(m)) {
     r[i,j] <- cor(m[,i], m[,j])
     r[j,i] <- r[i,j]
  }
}

all.equal(r, cor(m)) # Sanity check...

r # print resulting 11x11 correlation matrix
```

...Here I assume your correlation is symmetric and cor(x,x) == `1`.

**UPDATE** Since Vincent's solution is so much more elegant, I have to counter with the fact that mine is 2x faster :-)

```
# Huge data frame (1e6 rows, 10 cols)
d <- data.frame(matrix(1:1e7, ncol=10))

# Vincent's solution    
system.time(outer(
  names(d), 
  names(d), 
  r <- Vectorize(function(i,j) cor(d[,i],d[,j]))
)) # 2.25 secs

# My solution    
system.time({
m <- d
r <- matrix(1, ncol(m), ncol(m), dimnames=list(colnames(m), colnames(m)))
for(i in 1:(ncol(m)-1)) {
  for(j in (i+1):ncol(m)) {
     r[i,j] <- cor(m[,i], m[,j])
     r[j,i] <- r[i,j]
  }
}
}) # 1.0 secs
```

Comment: Works well.  R is my only language so I don't naturally think in loops.  Thank you. +1