# A matrix version of cor.test()

Tags: r, correlation

`Cor.test()` takes vectors `x` and `y` as arguments, but I have an entire matrix of data that I want to test, pairwise. `Cor()` takes this matrix as an argument just fine, and I'm hoping to find a way to do the same for `cor.test()`.

The common advice from other folks seems to be to use `cor.prob()`:

> https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2001-November/016201.html

But these p-values are not the same as those generated by `cor.test()`!!! `Cor.test()` also seems better equipped to handle pairwise deletion (I have quite a bit of missing data in my data set) than `cor.prob()`.

Does anybody have any alternatives to `cor.prob()`? If the solution involves nested for loops, so be it (I'm new enough to `R` for even this to be problematic for me).

Comment: You could use `lapply` with `cor.test` or vectorize the function and feed it to `outer` as seen in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917242/create-a-matrix-from-a-function-and-two-numeric-data-frames

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`corr.test` in the `psych` package is designed to do this:

```
library("psych")
data(sat.act)
corr.test(sat.act)
```

As noted in the comments, to replicate the *p*-values from the base `cor.test()` function over the entire matrix, then you need to turn off adjustment of the *p*-values for multiple comparisons (the default is to use Holm's method of adjustment):

```
 corr.test(sat.act, adjust = "none")
```

[But be careful when interpreting those results!]

Comment: beautiful, why reinvent the wheel.  +1g

Comment: Just a note if you want the results to match the stats `cor.test` use `corr.test(mtcars, adjust="none")`

Comment: Tyler, I noticed that. Thanks! Both of you have been awesome and super helpful!

Comment: If you have a big matrix, this will be very very slow! To speed it up, set the argument `ci=F` -- that takes about twice as long as cor() to run, whereas with `ci=T` (the default), it may take 100 times as long.

Comment: I got an error (Error in corr.test(x, y, adjust = "none", ci = F) : 
  object 'sef' not found) when I tried to do "ci = F". I wrote an answer below that takes the important code from the function and just runs cor() and gives the pvalues.

Answer (score 15):

If you're strictly after the pvalues in a matrix format from `cor.test` here's a solution shamelessly stolen from Vincent ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917242/create-a-matrix-from-a-function-and-two-numeric-data-frames)):

```
cor.test.p <- function(x){
    FUN <- function(x, y) cor.test(x, y)[["p.value"]]
    z <- outer(
      colnames(x), 
      colnames(x), 
      Vectorize(function(i,j) FUN(x[,i], x[,j]))
    )
    dimnames(z) <- list(colnames(x), colnames(x))
    z
}

cor.test.p(mtcars)
```

Note: Tommy also provides a faster solution though less easy to impliment.  Oh and no for loops :)

**Edit** I have a function `v_outer` in my `qdapTools` package that makes this task pretty easy:

```
library(qdapTools)
(out <- v_outer(mtcars, function(x, y) cor.test(x, y)[["p.value"]]))
print(out, digits=4)  # for more digits
```

Comment: Edited and `[[3]]` indexes the list that `cor.test` outputs.  The third element of this list is the p.value.

Comment: @TylerRinker I find that it's more clear in code if one uses the named version of the list output.  It's a little more clear if instead of `cor.test(x, y)[[3]]` you have `cor.test(x, y)[["p.value"]]` that you're extracting the p-value from the test.

Comment: @Dason I agree I just was lazy in that I guessed what the index was based on the output and was too lazy too use `str` or `names` on the out put from cor.test to find out.  I blame the bots really for this.  They've automated our lives to the point where we're just too lazy.

Comment: Are you saying that your proposal can reach the same result as `p.mat.all <- psych:::cor.test(M.cor, alternative = "two.sided", method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"), adjust = "none", ci = F)`? - - I think you just use Pearson cor here.

Comment: I love this method, so thank you! I needed to compute p-vals for multiple pairwise correlations, and rcorr was not running in my data because it was made of very large vectors. This did the trick! Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

Probably the easiest way is to use the `rcorr()` from Hmisc. It will only take a matrix, so use `rcorr(as.matrix(x))` if your data is in a data.frame. It will return you a list with: 1) matrix of r pairwise, 2) matrix of pairwise n, 3) matrix of p values for the r's. It automatically ignores missing data.

Ideally, a function of this kind should take data.frames too and also output confidence intervals in line with the '[New Statistics](http://pss.sagepub.com/content/early/2013/11/07/0956797613504966)'.

Comment: This is ideal, but it's not running on my large dataset (50 variables (that I am assessing their similarity) x 46,000,000 observations). Gives a memory error.

Comment: Try `wtd.cors()` from *weights* package. I think it uses some kind of approximation that's fast. If you need the p values etc., you can use `wtd.cor()` on each pairwise variable. If you still want more speed, you could look into doing one variable at a time and saving the z scores between computations, as this would save the operation of recalculating them a bunch of times.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution (corr.test function in the psych package) works, but is extremely slow for large matrices. I was working with a gene expression matrix (~20,000 by ~1,000) correlated to a drug sensitivity matrix (~1,000 by ~500) and I had to stop it because it was taking forever.

I took some code from the psych package and used the cor() function directly instead and got much better results:

```
# find (pairwise complete) correlation matrix between two matrices x and y
# compare to corr.test(x, y, adjust = "none")
n <- t(!is.na(x)) %*% (!is.na(y)) # same as count.pairwise(x,y) from psych package
r <- cor(x, y, use = "pairwise.complete.obs") # MUCH MUCH faster than corr.test()
cor2pvalue = function(r, n) {
  t <- (r*sqrt(n-2))/sqrt(1-r^2)
  p <- 2*(1 - pt(abs(t),(n-2)))
  se <- sqrt((1-r*r)/(n-2))
  out <- list(r, n, t, p, se)
  names(out) <- c("r", "n", "t", "p", "se")
  return(out)
}
# get a list with matrices of correlation, pvalues, standard error, etc.
result = cor2pvalue(r,n)
```

Even with two 100 x 200 matrices, the difference was staggering. A second or two versus 45 seconds.

```
> system.time(test_func(x,y))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.308   2.452   0.130 
> system.time(corr.test(x,y, adjust = "none"))
   user  system elapsed 
 45.004   3.276  45.814
```

Comment: Note: I just saw above that you can use corr.test() with "ci = F" option to make it faster. However, it gave me an error when I tried it.

Comment: Looks like there is a small bug in the code. See my fix here (I know it's read-only): https://github.com/cran/psych/pull/2/commits/903484b426699f291ba158754188582b929572de
I emailed the package maintainer about it.

Answer (score -1):

"The accepted solution (`corr.test` function in the psych package) works, but is extremely slow for large matrices."

If you use `ci=FALSE`, then the speed is much faster. 
By default, confidence intervals are found. However, this leads to a slight slowdown of speed. So, for just the `rs`, `ts` and `ps`, set `ci=FALSE`.