# How to get vennCounts() counts in R?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I want to get `vennCounts` data components of Venn's diagram as a row in R. 
Data components in Venn's diagram where N44 is about points outside circles (here 10)

[image]

Output of the code

[image]

Expected output with any separator

```
51 & 0 & 0 & 10 
& 0 & 0 & 10 &
50
```

Code to make Venn's diagrams from matrices

```
library('ggplot2')
library('limma') # vennCounts, vennDiagram
library("psych") # http://stackoverflow.com/a/13112799/54964 corr.test(M.cor, adjust = "none"), replaces default cor.test

makeVennCountsFromPMatrices <- function(M.cor) 
{    
  p.mat.all <- psych::corr.test(M.cor, adjust = "none", ci = F)
  alpha <- c(0.05)       
  p.mat.p <- (p.mat.all[["p"]] < alpha) # http://stackoverflow.com/a/6559049/54964
  p.mat.t <- (p.mat.all[["t"]] < alpha)
  p.mat.r <- (p.mat.all[["r"]] < alpha)

  # http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/venn.htm
  c3 <- cbind(c(p.mat.p), c(p.mat.t), c(p.mat.r))
  a <- vennCounts(c3)  

  str(a)

  vennDiagram(a, 
    names = c("1", "2", "3"), 
    cex = 2, counts = "red" 
  )
}

M.cor <- cor(mtcars)

makeVennCountsFromPMatrices(M.cor)
```

Output from `vennCounts` but nothing there seems to be about Nij counts

```
 VennCounts [1:8, 1:4] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:8] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "Group 1" "Group 2" "Group 3" "Counts"
```

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5