# Looking to see if two columns are independent or dependent in data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I'm looking to validate whether or not two columns in my data.frame are independent or dependent. I'm pretty sure I have a `working` function, but not sure if it's considered `"R-thonic"` to do it like this.

## Example Function Checking Column Dependence

```
#Identify which variables are independent of one another and dependent on each other
for (var1 in names(bmt)) {
  for (var2 in names(bmt)) {
    if (var1 != var2) {
      if (cor.test(bmt[[var1]], bmt[[var2]], method="spearman")$p.value <= 0.05) {
        cat(var1, " and ", var2, " are dependent.\n")
      } else {
        cat(var1, " and ", var2, " are independent.\n")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Data Set

```
> bmt
    group   t1   t2 d1 d2 d3   ta da   tc dc   tp dp z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6   z7 z8 z9 z10
1       1 2081 2081  0  0  0   67  1  121  1   13  1 26 33  1  0  1  1   98  0  1   0
2       1 1602 1602  0  0  0 1602  0  139  1   18  1 21 37  1  1  0  0 1720  0  1   0
3       1 1496 1496  0  0  0 1496  0  307  1   12  1 26 35  1  1  1  0  127  0  1   0
4       1 1462 1462  0  0  0   70  1   95  1   13  1 17 21  0  1  0  0  168  0  1   0
```

Is there a better way to tackle this using something like `sapply`?

Here is the output of the data using dput to load into R:

```
> dput(bmt)
structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), t1 = c(2081L, 1602L, 1496L, 1462L, 1433L, 1377L, 1330L, 996L, 
226L, 1199L, 1111L, 530L, 1182L, 1167L, 418L, 417L, 276L, 156L, 
781L, 172L, 487L, 716L, 194L, 371L, 526L, 122L, 1279L, 110L, 
243L, 86L, 466L, 262L, 162L, 262L, 1L, 107L, 269L, 350L, 2569L, 
2506L, 2409L, 2218L, 1857L, 1829L, 1562L, 1470L, 1363L, 1030L, 
860L, 1258L, 2246L, 1870L, 1799L, 1709L, 1674L, 1568L, 1527L, 
1324L, 957L, 932L, 847L, 848L, 1850L, 1843L, 1535L, 1447L, 1384L, 
414L, 2204L, 1063L, 481L, 105L, 641L, 390L, 288L, 522L, 79L, 
1156L, 583L, 48L, 431L, 1074L, 393L, 10L, 53L, 80L, 35L, 1499L, 
704L, 653L, 222L, 1356L, 2640L, 2430L, 2252L, 2140L, 2133L, 1238L, 
1631L, 2024L, 1345L, 1136L, 845L, 491L, 162L, 1298L, 121L, 2L, 
62L, 265L, 547L, 341L, 318L, 195L, 469L, 93L, 515L, 183L, 105L, 
128L, 164L, 129L, 122L, 80L, 677L, 73L, 168L, 74L, 16L, 248L, 
732L, 105L, 392L, 63L, 97L, 153L, 363L), t2 = c(2081L, 1602L, 
1496L, 1462L, 1433L, 1377L, 1330L, 996L, 226L, 1199L, 1111L, 
530L, 1182L, 1167L, 418L, 383L, 276L, 104L, 609L, 172L, 487L, 
662L, 194L, 230L, 526L, 122L, 129L, 74L, 122L, 86L, 466L, 192L, 
109L, 55L, 1L, 107L, 110L, 332L, 2569L, 2506L, 2409L, 2218L, 
1857L, 1829L, 1562L, 1470L, 1363L, 1030L, 860L, 1258L, 2246L, 
1870L, 1799L, 1709L, 1674L, 1568L, 1527L, 1324L, 957L, 932L, 
847L, 848L, 1850L, 1843L, 1535L, 1447L, 1384L, 414L, 2204L, 1063L, 
481L, 105L, 641L, 390L, 288L, 421L, 79L, 748L, 486L, 48L, 272L, 
1074L, 381L, 10L, 53L, 80L, 35L, 248L, 704L, 211L, 219L, 606L, 
2640L, 2430L, 2252L, 2140L, 2133L, 1238L, 1631L, 2024L, 1345L, 
1136L, 845L, 422L, 162L, 84L, 100L, 2L, 47L, 242L, 456L, 268L, 
318L, 32L, 467L, 47L, 390L, 183L, 105L, 115L, 164L, 93L, 120L, 
80L, 677L, 64L, 168L, 74L, 16L, 157L, 625L, 48L, 273L, 63L, 76L, 
113L, 363L), d1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), d2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), d3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), ta = c(67L, 1602L, 1496L, 70L, 1433L, 1377L, 1330L, 
72L, 226L, 1199L, 1111L, 38L, 1182L, 39L, 418L, 417L, 276L, 28L, 
781L, 22L, 487L, 716L, 194L, 371L, 526L, 88L, 1279L, 110L, 243L, 
86L, 466L, 10L, 162L, 262L, 1L, 107L, 269L, 350L, 2569L, 2506L, 
2409L, 2218L, 1857L, 1829L, 1562L, 1470L, 1363L, 1030L, 860L, 
1258L, 52L, 1870L, 1799L, 20L, 1674L, 1568L, 1527L, 25L, 957L, 
29L, 847L, 848L, 1850L, 1843L, 1535L, 1447L, 1384L, 414L, 2204L, 
1063L, 30L, 21L, 641L, 390L, 18L, 25L, 16L, 1156L, 583L, 48L, 
431L, 1074L, 393L, 10L, 53L, 10L, 35L, 1499L, 36L, 653L, 222L, 
1356L, 2640L, 2430L, 2252L, 2140L, 2133L, 1238L, 1631L, 2024L, 
32L, 1136L, 845L, 491L, 162L, 1298L, 28L, 2L, 62L, 265L, 547L, 
21L, 318L, 195L, 469L, 93L, 515L, 183L, 105L, 128L, 164L, 129L, 
122L, 21L, 677L, 73L, 168L, 29L, 16L, 248L, 732L, 105L, 392L, 
38L, 97L, 153L, 363L), da = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), tc = c(121L, 139L, 307L, 95L, 236L, 123L, 96L, 121L, 226L, 
91L, 1111L, 84L, 112L, 487L, 220L, 417L, 81L, 156L, 781L, 172L, 
76L, 716L, 94L, 184L, 121L, 122L, 1279L, 110L, 243L, 86L, 119L, 
84L, 162L, 262L, 1L, 107L, 120L, 350L, 2569L, 2506L, 2409L, 2218L, 
260L, 1829L, 1562L, 180L, 200L, 210L, 860L, 120L, 380L, 230L, 
140L, 348L, 1674L, 1568L, 1527L, 1324L, 957L, 932L, 847L, 155L, 
1850L, 1843L, 1535L, 220L, 200L, 414L, 2204L, 240L, 120L, 105L, 
641L, 390L, 100L, 140L, 79L, 180L, 583L, 48L, 431L, 120L, 100L, 
10L, 53L, 80L, 35L, 1499L, 155L, 653L, 123L, 1356L, 2640L, 2430L, 
150L, 220L, 250L, 250L, 150L, 180L, 360L, 140L, 845L, 180L, 162L, 
1298L, 121L, 2L, 62L, 210L, 130L, 100L, 140L, 195L, 90L, 93L, 
515L, 130L, 105L, 128L, 164L, 129L, 122L, 80L, 150L, 73L, 200L, 
74L, 16L, 100L, 732L, 105L, 122L, 63L, 97L, 153L, 363L), dc = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), tp = c(13L, 18L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 
12L, 17L, 12L, 10L, 29L, 22L, 34L, 22L, 1167L, 21L, 16L, 21L, 
20L, 26L, 37L, 22L, 17L, 25L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 22L, 49L, 23L, 86L, 
100L, 59L, 40L, 24L, 1L, 107L, 27L, 33L, 21L, 17L, 16L, 11L, 
15L, 19L, 18L, 14L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 66L, 15L, 16L, 12L, 19L, 24L, 
14L, 13L, 15L, 69L, 7L, 16L, 16L, 9L, 19L, 21L, 24L, 19L, 27L, 
12L, 16L, 24L, 15L, 11L, 11L, 288L, 20L, 79L, 18L, 11L, 14L, 
12L, 19L, 16L, 10L, 53L, 80L, 35L, 9L, 18L, 23L, 52L, 14L, 22L, 
14L, 17L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 40L, 16L, 14L, 15L, 20L, 491L, 13L, 
1298L, 65L, 2L, 11L, 14L, 24L, 17L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 28L, 31L, 
21L, 105L, 12L, 164L, 51L, 12L, 0L, 8L, 38L, 48L, 24L, 16L, 52L, 
18L, 30L, 24L, 16L, 97L, 59L, 19L), dp = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), z1 = c(26L, 21L, 26L, 17L, 32L, 22L, 20L, 22L, 
18L, 24L, 19L, 17L, 24L, 27L, 18L, 15L, 18L, 20L, 27L, 40L, 22L, 
28L, 26L, 39L, 15L, 20L, 17L, 28L, 37L, 17L, 15L, 29L, 36L, 23L, 
42L, 30L, 29L, 22L, 19L, 31L, 35L, 16L, 29L, 19L, 26L, 27L, 13L, 
25L, 25L, 30L, 45L, 33L, 32L, 23L, 37L, 15L, 22L, 46L, 18L, 27L, 
28L, 23L, 37L, 34L, 35L, 33L, 21L, 21L, 25L, 50L, 35L, 37L, 26L, 
50L, 45L, 28L, 43L, 14L, 17L, 32L, 30L, 30L, 33L, 34L, 33L, 30L, 
23L, 35L, 29L, 23L, 28L, 33L, 18L, 29L, 35L, 27L, 36L, 24L, 27L, 
35L, 50L, 47L, 40L, 22L, 22L, 8L, 39L, 20L, 27L, 32L, 31L, 20L, 
35L, 36L, 35L, 7L, 23L, 11L, 14L, 37L, 19L, 37L, 25L, 35L, 15L, 
45L, 32L, 41L, 27L, 33L, 39L, 17L, 43L, 44L, 48L, 31L, 52L), 
    z2 = c(33L, 37L, 35L, 21L, 36L, 31L, 17L, 24L, 21L, 40L, 
    28L, 28L, 23L, 22L, 14L, 20L, 5L, 33L, 27L, 37L, 20L, 32L, 
    32L, 31L, 20L, 26L, 20L, 25L, 38L, 26L, 18L, 32L, 43L, 16L, 
    48L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 13L, 34L, 31L, 16L, 35L, 18L, 30L, 34L, 
    24L, 29L, 31L, 16L, 39L, 30L, 23L, 28L, 34L, 19L, 12L, 31L, 
    17L, 30L, 29L, 26L, 36L, 32L, 32L, 28L, 18L, 15L, 19L, 38L, 
    36L, 34L, 24L, 48L, 43L, 30L, 43L, 19L, 14L, 33L, 23L, 32L, 
    28L, 54L, 41L, 35L, 25L, 18L, 21L, 16L, 30L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 
    31L, 17L, 39L, 28L, 21L, 41L, 36L, 27L, 39L, 21L, 23L, 2L, 
    48L, 19L, 25L, 32L, 28L, 23L, 40L, 39L, 33L, 2L, 25L, 7L, 
    18L, 35L, 32L, 34L, 29L, 28L, 14L, 42L, 43L, 29L, 36L, 39L, 
    43L, 14L, 50L, 37L, 56L, 25L, 48L), z3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), z4 = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), z5 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), z6 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), z7 = c(98L, 1720L, 127L, 
    168L, 93L, 2187L, 1006L, 1319L, 208L, 174L, 236L, 151L, 203L, 
    191L, 110L, 824L, 146L, 85L, 187L, 129L, 128L, 84L, 329L, 
    147L, 943L, 2616L, 937L, 303L, 170L, 239L, 508L, 74L, 393L, 
    331L, 196L, 178L, 361L, 834L, 270L, 60L, 120L, 60L, 90L, 
    210L, 90L, 240L, 90L, 210L, 180L, 180L, 105L, 225L, 120L, 
    90L, 60L, 90L, 450L, 75L, 90L, 60L, 75L, 180L, 180L, 270L, 
    180L, 150L, 120L, 120L, 60L, 270L, 90L, 120L, 90L, 120L, 
    90L, 90L, 90L, 60L, 120L, 150L, 120L, 150L, 120L, 240L, 180L, 
    150L, 150L, 30L, 105L, 90L, 120L, 210L, 750L, 24L, 120L, 
    210L, 240L, 240L, 690L, 105L, 120L, 900L, 210L, 210L, 300L, 
    105L, 210L, 75L, 90L, 180L, 630L, 180L, 300L, 90L, 120L, 
    135L, 210L, 120L, 150L, 270L, 285L, 240L, 510L, 780L, 150L, 
    180L, 150L, 750L, 180L, 180L, 150L, 210L, 240L, 360L, 330L, 
    240L, 180L), z8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), z9 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), z10 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L)), .Names = c("group", "t1", "t2", "d1", "d2", "d3", "ta", 
"da", "tc", "dc", "tp", "dp", "z1", "z2", "z3", "z4", "z5", "z6", 
"z7", "z8", "z9", "z10"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-137L))
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing being uncorrelated  and being independent.

Comment: Ok, so independence implies being uncorrelated, but not the other way around? Do you have resources as to how I would go about determining independence in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A matrix version of cor.test()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112238/a-matrix-version-of-cor-test)

Comment: What does `bmt` look like? Could you give us a reproducible example?

Comment: @ycw added to OP

Comment: @ycw Did you import the data correctly? I'm not getting any errors with my output.

Comment: It is possible that I did not import the data correctly. I am using `read.table()`. It would be easier if you can use `dput` to share the data.

Comment: Use `dput()` to provide the date. That makes things easier.

Comment: I've added the dput output

Comment: It is common enough to use the Spearman correlation test as a test for dependence,. If you reject the null hypothesis of independence, then you have evidence of dependence. But it is fallacious to say that you have proved independence just because you haven't rejected the null hypothesis. For one thing, that isn't how statistical tests work (not being convicted doesn't prove innocence) and for another thing, in this case it confuses independence and being uncorrelated. You could look into chi-squared tests for independence.

Answer (score 1):

There must be many ways to achieve this task. Here I introduce my solution using the `tidyverse` package.

Your for-loop works well. However, I prefer a solution that can store all relevant information in a data frame. `tidyverse` is very handy in terms of manipulating data in a data frame.

First, I converted the `bmt` from wide format to long format and then created a nested data frame

```
library(tidyverse)

bmt2 <- bmt %>%
  gather(Var1, Value) %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  nest()
```

Nested data frame could be a relatively new concept. However, if you type `bmt2$data[[1]]` as an example. You can see that all the data from the `group` column (the first row of `bmt2`) are stored as a sub-data frame.

Next, I use the `complete` function to create all combination between each variable, and then combine with the values. Notice that the last three lines with `mutate_at` and `arrange` is to sort the data frame based on the order of the column name in `bmt`. Howevet, if the order is not important, this step is optional.

```
bmt3 <- bmt2 %>%
  select(Var1) %>%
  mutate(Var2 = Var1) %>%
  complete(Var1, Var2) %>%
  filter(Var2 != Var1) %>%
  left_join(bmt2, by = "Var1") %>%
  left_join(bmt2, by = c("Var2" = "Var1")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Var")), funs(factor(., levels = colnames(bmt)))) %>%
  arrange(Var1, Var2) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Var")), funs(as.character(.)))
```

After the expanded data frame is ready, I can use `map2_dbl` to apply the cor.test function. I stored the P value in the `Corr_Pvalue` column.

```
bmt4 <- bmt3 %>%
  mutate(Corr_Pvalue = map2_dbl(data.x, data.y, 
                         ~cor.test(.x$Value, .y$Value, method = "spearman")$p.value))
```

I can also create a new column called `Message` by the `mutate` and `ifelse` call showing the if variables are "dependent" or "independent".

```
bmt5 <- bmt4 %>%
  select(-data.x, -data.y) %>%
  mutate(Message = ifelse(Corr_Pvalue <= 0.05, "dependent", "independent"))
```

Now take a look at `bmt5`, we see that each combination all have an associated P value and dependent" or "independent" information. `bmt5` is a data frame with summary information, which could be useful for future analysis.

```
bmt5
# A tibble: 462 x 4
    Var1  Var2 Corr_Pvalue     Message
   <chr> <chr>       <dbl>       <chr>
 1 group    t1   0.2240859 independent
 2 group    t2   0.2068429 independent
 3 group    d1   0.1691849 independent
 4 group    d2   0.0906152 independent
 5 group    d3   0.1769669 independent
 6 group    ta   0.9899871 independent
 7 group    da   0.2254046 independent
 8 group    tc   0.8407693 independent
 9 group    dc   0.2719835 independent
10 group    tp   0.9103147 independent
# ... with 452 more rows
```

Finally, if you want to print the information as your for-loop did, we can use the `writeLines`. It prints each string with a new line.

```
writeLines(text = paste0(bmt5$Var1, " and ", 
                         bmt5$Var2, " are ", 
                         bmt5$Message, ".")) 

group and t1 are independent.
group and t2 are independent.
group and d1 are independent.
group and d2 are independent.
group and d3 are independent.
group and ta are independent.
group and da are independent.
group and tc are independent.
group and dc are independent.
group and tp are independent.
group and dp are independent.
group and z1 are dependent.
...
```