# Faster i, j matrix cell fill

Tags: r, performance, data.table, dplyr

I want to take columns of a data.frame/matrix and apply a function to between each cell (`[i, j]`) of the dataframe where i and j are the sequences along the columns of the data.frame.  Basically I want to fill a matrix of individual cells in the same way that the `cor` function works with a data.frame.

This is a related question: [Create a matrix from a function and two numeric data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917242/create-a-matrix-from-a-function-and-two-numeric-data-frames)  However, I use this in randomization tests and repeat the operation many times (make many matrices).  I'm looking for the fastest way to do this operation.  I have sped things up a bit using parallel processing but I'm still not happy with this speed.  It can not be assumed that the matrix output is symmetrical either, that is in the way `cor` produces a symmetrical matrix (my example will reflect this).

I saw on the data.table web page today (http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) the following:

> 500+ times faster than `DF[i,j]<-value`

This got me thinking that perhaps `data.table` or `dplyr` or other means may speed things up a bit.  My brain has been fixed on filling cells but maybe there's a better way involving reshaping, applying the function and reshaping to a matrix or something along those lines.  I can achieve this in base R using `outer` or a `for` loop as follows.

```
## Arbitrary function
FUN <- function(x, y) round(sqrt(sum(x)) - sum(y), digits=1)

## outer approach
outer(
  names(mtcars), 
  names(mtcars), 
  Vectorize(function(i,j) FUN(mtcars[,i],mtcars[,j]))
)

## for approach
mat <- matrix(rep(NA, ncol(mtcars)^2), ncol(mtcars))
for (i in 1:ncol(mtcars)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(mtcars)) {
        mat[i, j] <- FUN(mtcars[, i], mtcars[, j])
    }
}
mat
```

Here are the [microbenchmark](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/index.html) timings with `for` getting a slight edge.

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 OUTER() 4.450410 4.691124 4.774394 4.877724 55.77333  1000
   FOR() 4.309527 4.521785 4.588728 4.694156  7.04275  1000
```

What is the fastest approach to this in R (add on packages welcomed)?

Comment: What is the dimension of your real data set approx.?

Comment: It can vary considerably, from 10 X 10 to 1000 X 1000

Comment: Since you say the function is arbitrary, it's not easy to tell if the function itself can be vectorised. I mean, here, you could calculate `colSums(mat)` once, and `sqrt(.)` once, and then generate the combinations using `expand.grid` (or `CJ` - faster, from `data.table`). Without knowing the amount of vectorisation possible, I can only suggest C or Rcpp.

Comment: @Arun that's pretty sensible.  I was looking for a generic code that I can use with any function.  I think the `CJ` idea may give me something to try and bench.  But yeah vectorial ion on the function is very importamt.

Comment: use `.subset2(mtcars, i)` instead of `mtcars[, i]` and you'll get a 4-5x speedup

Comment: this question is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20125947/817778

Comment: @eddi this gives substantial speedup to both outer and for and combined with gagolews's approach you get even more speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still sticking to `base` R solution, I got a 1.6-1.7x speedup in the `for`-based approach by:

- substituting `[,i]` for `[[i]]` (significant time impact - perhaps `FUN` just receives C pointers here instead of freshly allocated vectors);
- byte-code compiling of `FUN` (small time impact);
- wrapping `for` code to a function + byte-code compilation (small time impact);

BTW, swapping indices (i,j) -> (j,i) in the 2 loops didn't result in significant differences (theoretically, row-wise matrix access should be faster).

Code:

```
library(compiler)
FUN2 <- cmpfun(FUN)
for2 <- cmpfun(function(mtcars, FUN) {
      mat <- matrix(rep(NA, ncol(mtcars)^2), ncol(mtcars))
   for (i in 1:ncol(mtcars)) {
       for (j in 1:ncol(mtcars)) {
           mat[i, j] <- FUN(mtcars[[i]], mtcars[[j]])
       }
   }
   mat
})
```

Benchmarks:

```
 Unit: milliseconds
                min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 outer     7.791739 7.991474 8.245869 8.538163 16.24460   100
 for       8.143679 8.463249 8.588230 9.912008 16.30842   100
 for-mods  4.713837 4.875972 5.006202 5.246584 15.66491   100
```

In my opinion, it will be difficult to find a much faster approach (but I may be wrong). The `for` loop time bias is quite small (ca. 0.25 ms) comparing to the time needed to compute `FUN` multiple times.

Comment: Nice.  Even if others come up with faster approaches I learned `[[i]]` is faster than `[, i]`.  +1