# Fast rdist replacement in R accepting custom distance metric

Tags: r, field, metric

I have to calculate the pairwise distances of two-dimensional points. These points are stored in a matrix, the first column containing the x values, the second column the y values. The distance function I need is not the euclidean metric though, but some custom metric.

For the euclidean distance, using the `rdist()` function from the `fields` package would give me what I want:

```
require(fields)
a = matrix(c(0,7,3,2,0,8,2,8), nrow=4)
b = matrix(c(2,6,2,6,2,2,6,6), nrow=4)
rdist(a,b)

         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 2.828427 6.324555 6.324555 8.485281
[2,] 7.810250 6.082763 5.385165 2.236068
[3,] 1.000000 3.000000 4.123106 5.000000
[4,] 6.000000 7.211103 2.000000 4.472136
```

To use my own metric, I wrote a simple `rdist()` replacement that calculates the distance of the points:

```
my_rdist <- function(a, b) {
    a_len = dim(a)[1]
    b_len = dim(b)[1]
    distmatrix = matrix(data=NA, nrow=a_len, ncol=b_len)
    for(i in seq(1,a_len)) {
        for(j in seq(1,b_len)) {
            distmatrix[i,j] = my_distance( a[i,], b[j,] )
        }
    }
    return(distmatrix)
}
```

This also works as expected, but it's painfully slow. The `my_rdist()` function takes about 20 minutes where the `rdist()` function from the `fields` package needs less than 2 seconds. (The custom metric at the moment just computes the square of the euclidean distance. The idea is to kind of penalize larger distances in the following processing of my data set.)

Are there any replacements for `rdist()` I'm not aware of that can handle custom metric functions? Or can you provide me with any hints to speed up my `my_rdist()`function? I'm pretty new to `R` so perhaps I've made some obvious mistakes.

Comment: This is a question I asked yesterday that is related, which may give some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817341/faster-i-j-matrix-cell-fill/23817578#23817578

Comment: Run a `Rprof` to see whether it's your `my_distance` which is the time pig here.

Comment: @Carl it's indeed `my_distance` that slows down the script. Replacing its body with a simple `return(1)` decreases the runtime down to less than 4 seconds. @Tyler, your question revealed a crucial hint: I used the `x[i]` notation to access the vector elements. Just replacing it with `x[[i]]` decreases the runtime from 20 minutes to less than 2 minutes.